# JayData saveChanges() error with IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, jaydata

I'm having trouble deleting data from IndexedDb.   The methods works fine with WebSql but throws an error with IndexedDb.  Initial population seems to work ok.

This error is in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ABORT_ERR' of undefined IndexedDbProvider.js:627
self.db.transaction.setCallbacks.onerror
```

the code has been moved to [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WasCz/4/)

It's worth noting there is no error if I simply call `remove()`.  The error appears to happen exclusively when I attempt to `saveChanges()`.

Seeing as I (potentially) have your attention is `toArray` and `forEach` synchronous?  so I could reduce transactions on the save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dvContext.Data.remove(data) is just a typo ? should be dContext.Datas.remove(data);

Some of JayData's functions are sync and other methods are async but in a logical way :)
When JayData touches the local database or calls a remote method over the network then those functions are async. Let's go through your code:

```
 dContext.Datas
```

is a filter (Queryable) which selects all records, as long as you just build the filter the calls are sync, so

```
dContext.Datas.filter().take().skip().orderBy().map()
```

just builds up the filter in memory and does nothing else so they're all sync, then:

```
dContext.Datas.toArray()
```

toArray fires the real actions, executes the query, here we have to touch the local database, so it is async, and when it finished it can call a callback function or resolves the promise it returned earlier.

The same applies to remove, it just drops the record into a set (so it's sync) and saveChanges() does the real work (it's async).

Your problem imho is that your toArray has both a callback function and a then branch so both will be called parallel and the then branch will not wait for the finish of the callback. The solution:

```
dContext.Datas.toArray()
.then(function(data) {
     // your removes in a loop
     // important: return the promise
     return dContext.saveChanges();
})
.then(function() {
     // whatever
})
```

Comment: also, when JayData returns data and you remove then with forEach, it's plain javascript and sync

Comment: hey Gabor, I wrote a fiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/WasCz/4/ (you have to run it twice to see the error)

Comment: your original (flawed) code resulted an error but the error handling part of JayData failed, because that error code has been removed :(

Comment: also, you do not have to manually set the provider, 'local' will select the best available local provider

Comment: Hello, I have made the changes you suggested and its interesting to know that remove is in memory until save is executed.  I still get the same error.  Here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WasCz/6/  (Sorry Ignore this I didn't see your comments!)

Comment: JayData original API (JSQL) was modelled after Entity Framework / LINQ and there remove() also just flags the record for deletion and saveChanges() does the real work. The API was modelled after that product but we do not need it to work!!! Later we created a simplified API (ItemStore API) where the syntax is simpler, so instance.remove() really removes the instance. It easier but for example you can not do batch delete with ItemStore API, with saveChanges() you can delete records in a batch which can be handy over oData for example.

Comment: haha, I can only apologise, your example works - I even think my second one did!  I have no idea what's going on with the comments.  I'm just getting myself in a flap.  Moral of the story THANK YOU.